# Could the screen of apple watch be scrolling/paging style?

Tags: watchkit, scroll-paging

If I want to design things on the Apple Watch with many contents then exceeds the screen, could it be scroll or paged?

Comment: Like what ? I mean a bottom up scroll or what ?

Comment: @iOSNoob yeah scroll from the bottom to continue the content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It does. WKInterface allows you to scroll to bottom/up when content is more than the screen size. As you keep on adding the content to interface, Watchkit will automatically create scroll that allows you to view the content to the bottom. Second one is horizontal scrolling page by page. In WatchKit there is only one way to do horizontal page based scrolling. You have to set up a page based UI. You will have to have a new instance of a controller for each page. See [link](http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-page-based-navigation/) for more info.

Comment: Totally got that! Thank you!